# Proper way to read data from HttpURLConnection depending on responsecode

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

What is the proper way to read data from right stream depending on responsecode?

Here is the way I'm doing it now:

```
private String getData(int responseCode, HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    if (responseCode > 220) {
        return NetworkUtil.readFromStream(connection.getErrorStream());
    } else {
        return NetworkUtil.readFromStream(connection.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

It works, but what is with response codes like `304 (not modified)`?

Comment: If it isn't modified there is no data.

Comment: @EJP was just an example, bad example...

Answer (score 0):

You have a list [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) with http response codes, you should check with this your response code and use a switch to do your logic, something better would be implement a component with the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) yo allow different behaviours depending on the response code, but this will take more time.

Comment: There is no `Enum` at your link.

Comment: Yes, there are static integers, sorry, im editing but, anyway is what a reference point for the http codes